# Bitnami Wordpress refuses to change upload limit, ignores PHP.ini, wp-config.php, and .htaccess file

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

Sorry guys, don't know where else to turn. I'm running bitnami wordpress hosted in Amazon lightsail, and the file upload limit is stuck at 80M.

I want it to be significantly more than that, but no matter what I change bitnami ignores it.

I put this in the .htaccess file:

> php_value upload_max_filesize 256M

*Ignored by Bitnami*

I put this in wp-config.php:

> @ini_set( 'upload_max_filesize' , '256M' )

*Ignored by Bitnami*

I changed this variable in php.ini:

> upload_max_filesize = 256M

Then created phpinfo.php file to verify that apache2 / wordpress is pointing to the correct php.ini (it is).

*STILL IGNORED BY BITNAMI.* PHP INFO SAYS IT'S POINTED TO THE RIGHT PHP.INI FILE **BUT IGNORES THE REAL MAX UPLOAD VALUE AND SHOWS MAX UPLOAD VALUE AS 80M**

WTF!?

I of course also restarted the server, restarted apache, and restarted the PHP service a bunch of times.

Does Bitnami have some kind of special hidden troll area where they set this value in a place it's not supposed to be so nobody can find and change it? That's the only explanation I can think of...

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this was defined in the directory section of the Virtualhost (Apache2)?
Example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName www.test.com
 [...]
 php_admin_value upload_max_filesize 100M
 [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Oh, maybe so, where's this located on the server?

Comment: This is a good question that your server admin can answer for you.